# If two values checked, NSString should be...?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created checkboxes in my iOS app. I'm trying to write code that says, "if box 8 is checked AND box 9 is checked, self.skillSet = "Sentence one and sentence two". How might I go about this? Currently, my code says the following:

> If box 8 is checked, than self.skillSet = Sentence one - if box 9 is checked, self.skillSet = sentence two.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)oralCheck:(id)sender {

    if (!checked8) {
        [self.oralValue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked8 = YES;

        self.skillSet = @"Sentence One";
        NSLog(@"%@", self.skillSet);
    }
    else if (checked8) {
        [self.oralValue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked8 = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)injectedCheck:(id)sender {

    if (!checked9) {
        [self.injectValue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked9 = YES;

        self.skillSet = @"Sentence Two";
        NSLog(@"%@", self.skillSet);
    }
    else if (checked9) {
        [self.injectValue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedwhite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked9 = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you are asking, but is this is?

```
if checked9 && checked8 {
    self.skillSet = "Sentence one and sentence two"
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yes. Ok so newb question: Does the ! in front of checked9 mean, "If box 9 is not checked" ?

Comment: ! will toggle the bool value (true -> false and false -> true)

Answer (score 0):

From this way also you can achieve

```
if (checked9 && checked8) {
     self.skillSet = [self.skillSet stringByAppendingString:@" "];
     self.skillSet = [self.skillSet stringByAppendingString:@"and sentence Two"];
}
```